# Use of WNetAddConnection2 in Azure WebSite

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to use the WinAPI function WNetAddConnection2 from within a Azure App Service WebSite? If I call the function I get an error code which I think translates to 'Access Denied'.

Also, I am not mapping the network to a local name (i.e. drive letter).

Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53008248